# Classes that don't implement all interface methods

Tags: java, oop, interface

I asked a question on [this forum](https://www.gamedev.net/topic/688587-when-one-object-can-be-used-multiple-ways/) about how to structure my code, give that an object can be used in more than one way.

I had a weapon class that looked like this:

```
public interface Weapon {
     void attack();
}
```

and a Reloable interface:

```
public interface Reload {
     void Reload(Bullet bullets);
}
```

It was suggested that I combine my reload method with the Weapon interface, however, **not all Weapons are reloadable**. According to the users, I could check if the Weapon was reloadable with a boolean, so my Weapon interface is now:

```
public interface Weapon {
     void attack();
     boolean isReloadable();
     void Reload(Bullet bullets);
}
```

If the weapon isn't reloadable, then the boolean will return false, and the method reload will be left empty. Doesn't that violate the principal that all methods of an interface should be implemented? Is there an alternative?

Comment: In my opinion, is better to implement a Class hierarchy: an abstract class Weapon which contains all attributes and methods commons to all kind of weapons (such as `attack()`), and then a class for each  particular kind of weapon should extend it, so the Class `ReloadableWeapon extends Weapons implements Reload` and implements also the `reload()` method.

Answer (score 1):

An idea to move reloading into a separate interface lets you mix and match your interfaces as needed when defining your classes. If a weapon is not reloadable, do not implement `Reloadable` interface in classes that model it.

Here is an example:

```
class AK47 implements Weapon, Reloadable {
    public void attack() {
        System.out.println("rat-a-tat");
    }
    public void reload(Bullet bullets) {
        System.out.println("+30 rounds");
    }
}
class Chainsaw implements Weapon {
    public void attack() {
        System.out.println("Bzzzz");
    }
}
```

You can use `instanceof` operator to test if an instance of `Weapon` is `Reloadable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use an abstract class and declare the methods with an empty body that don't really need to be initialized by other classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of dessign, with the approach you posted would be better throwing an 
**[UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)** if someone call `reload()` on an not re-loadable weapon instead of leaving the method empty/unimplemented....

Answer (score 0):

you have to know the contract of your interface.
Weapon attacks and reloads.

```
public interface Weapon {
 void attack();
 void reload(Bullet bullets);
}
```

To check if the weapon is re-loadable doesn't belong to the contract but it's just a candition to execute reload method, then it's a commun behavior, and when we talk about common ,we talk about a mother class .

You need to have an abstract class that implements this interface.

```
public abstarct class AbstractWeapon implements Weapon {
 public abstract void attack();
 public void reload(Bullet bullets){
   if (isReloadable())
     reloadBullet(bullets);

 }
public abstract void reloadBullet(Bullet bullets);
public abstract boolean isReloadable();
}
```

Your class Weapon (ak12) for example  inherits AbstractWeapon  and will be able to implement three methods reloadBullet and attack and isReloadable ,like this:

```
 public class Ak12 extends  AbstractWeapon{
 public  void attack(){
  //TO IMPELEMENT
 }

public void reloadBullet(Bullet bullets){
  //to implement
}
public abstract boolean isReloadable(){
//To implement
}
}
```

finnally, you can reference your ak12 by your interface:

```
Weapon ak12 =new Ak12();
```

and your ak12 attacks and reloads and respects your is re-loadable condition

Answer (score 0):

I think define **Reload** as a separate interface is better,then you can **set reload implement dynamic**：

```
public abstract class AbstractWeapon implements Weapon{
    private Reload reload = EmptyReload.instance();  //default do nothing

    public Reload getReload() {
        return reload;
    }

    public void setReload(Reload reload) {
        this.reload = reload;
    }

    //add reload method 
    public void reLoad(Bullet bullets){
        reload.reload(bullets);
    }
}
```

**EmptyReload** is a empty object do nothing:

```
public class EmptyReload implements Reload{

    private static EmptyReload emptyReload = new EmptyReload();

    private EmptyReload() {
    }

    public static EmptyReload instance(){
        return emptyReload;
    }

    @Override
    public void Reload(Bullet bullets) {
        //can not reload,do nothing
    }
}
```

then your gun implement:

```
public class Gun extends AbstractWeapon{
    public Gun() {
        setReload(bullets -> System.out.println("reload bullets"));
    }

    @Override
    public void attack() {
        //impl
    }
}
```

or change its reload implement when you want:

```
Gun gun = new Gun();
gun.setReload(bullets -> System.out.println("switch reload interface"));
```